# Smoother Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So instead of tkinter, I am using customtkinter for my python GUIs. So what I am trying to do is whenever a user clicks a button in my project the frame changes to another frame

**Example:**

```
def analytics_win():
    if frame_main_win.winfo_ismapped():
        frame_main_win.pack_forget()
    elif encrypt_frame_win.winfo_ismapped():
        encrypt_frame_win.pack_forget()
    elif decrypt_frame_win.winfo_ismapped():
        decrypt_frame_win.pack_forget()
    elif keys_frame_win.winfo_ismapped():
        keys_frame_win.pack_forget()
    elif settings_frame_win.winfo_ismapped():
        settings_frame_win.pack_forget()
    analytics_frame_win.pack()
```

In this method I have observed a lot of delay as well as creation and removal of tkinter widgets when the button is clicked.

**Suggestion:**
Is there a better way to perform this action making tkinter frames to switch smoother and also make the project efficient.

Comment: You can use a variable that will keep track of which window is packed so that you can remove all of the `winfo_ismapped` calls. `tkinter` is quite slow as `tkinter` is just a wrapper for `tcl`. So try to not overdo the number of `tkinter` calls.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed example. I couldn't quite reach your point

Comment: It depends on the context of your program. Can 2 frames be `pack`ed at the same time? In what cases is `analytics_win` called? How is your program structured? Can you give a [mre]?

Comment: You can put all of those widgets in a `tkinter.Frame` and just call `.pack_forget()` on that. That way, all of the sub-frames will be removed from the screen as well. Also if you aren't going to use widgets later, you can just destroy them. I also recommend that you look at some `tkinter` tutorials as `customtkinter` is built on top of `tkinter` and functions very similarly.

Comment: That's a good idea I will try that and will let you know if I got a reduction in execution time.

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried the method you describes but the process execution time and frame displaying abnormality is still there maybe that's the max execution efficiency I can reach.

Answer (score 0):

So my code is like this:

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (1600, 900, (app.winfo_screenwidth()/2) - (1600/2), (app.winfo_screenheight()/2) - (900/2)))
app.title("enigma:guard")
app.resizable("False", "False")


#frame calling function
def encryption_frame_call():
    analytics_frame.pack_forget()
    encryption_frame.pack()


#images
analytics_frame_bg_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\sec_win.png"), dark_image=Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\sec_win.png"),size=(1600,900))

encryption_frame_bg_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\encryption_main.png"), dark_image=Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\encryption_main.png"),size=(1600,900))


#analytics frame
analytics_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, width=1600, height=900)
analytics_frame.pack()

analytics_frame_bg = customtkinter.CTkLabel(analytics_frame, text="", image=analytics_frame_bg_img)
analytics_frame_bg.pack()

analytics_tab = customtkinter.CTkButton(analytics_frame_bg, text="",image=analytics_tab_img,bg_color="#1FFFA9",fg_color="#1FFFA9",hover=False)
analytics_tab.place(x=17,y=330)

encrypt_deselect_tab = customtkinter.CTkButton(analytics_frame_bg, text="",image=encryption_tab_deselect_img,bg_color="#1FFFA9",fg_color="#1FFFA9",hover=False,command=encryption_frame_call)
encrypt_deselect_tab.place(x=17,y=424) 


#encryption frame
encryption_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, width=1600, height=900)
encryption_frame.pack()

encryption_frame_bg = customtkinter.CTkLabel(encryption_frame, text="", image=encryption_frame_bg_img)
encryption_frame_bg.pack()

analytics_deselect_tab = customtkinter.CTkButton(encryption_frame_bg, text="",image=analytics_tab_deselect_img,bg_color="#1FFFA9",fg_color="#1FFFA9",hover=False,command=analytics_frame)
analytics_deselect_tab.place(x=17,y=330)

encrypt_tab = customtkinter.CTkButton(encryption_frame_bg, text="",image=encryption_tab_img,bg_color="#1FFFA9",fg_color="#1FFFA9",hover=False)
encrypt_tab.place(x=17,y=424)


app.mainloop()
```

So when I click on the encryption_tab button the analytics frame disappear and the encryption frame appears but there is still visible laggy transition present in their.